# FILE INPUT INSERT INTO BD WITH MOVE_TO_FILE

Tags: php, html

This is more of a question to gain a more clear understanding. If I insert from a form like:

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
```

into the DB for a link and it's successful:

```
 $file = "INSERT INTO ('foo') VALUES ('FOO', NOW())";
```

just an example:

yet in the php script:

```
  $_FILE['fileToUpload']['name'];
  $_FILE['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
```

since the tmp_name folder only holds upload files in an array, which than I would have to use either a foreach or for loop search the loop of files, this than makes the INSERT INTO db difficult.

Question is how can I separate the search results from the array and than insert each one into the database?

HERE"S THE CODE:

```
     <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","acc1");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL:' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo 'Connected!';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['fileBC']['name'] && !empty($_FILES['fileB']['name'] && !empty($_FILES['fileBR']['name']) ))){

     $file = "image/";
     $name = $_FILES['fileBC']['name'];
     $data = $_FILES['fileBC']['tmp_name'];
     $fileV = "video/";
     $nameV = $_FILES['fileBR']['name'];
     $dataV = $_FILES['fileBR']['tmp_name'];
     $fileB = "book/";
     $nameB = $_FILES['fileB']['name'];
     $dataB = $_FILES['fileB']['tmp_name'];
     if(move_uploaded_file($data,$file.$name)){
         $ins_name = $con->query("INSERT INTO fileimages (fileBC, fileBR, fileB) VALUES ('$name','$nameB', '$nameV')");
     }if($ins_name){ 
         echo 'success!';
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
  }

     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html> 

       <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.css">
     <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
     function mymodal(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }

    </script>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-primary">Book Cover:</label>
            <input  class="form-control" type="file" name="fileBC" accept="image/*" >
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-primary">Book:</label>
            <input  class="form-control" type="file" name="fileB" accept=".epub, .mobi, .pdf, .prc, .azw, .bbeb" >
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-primary">Book Reading:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="fileBR" accept="video/*" >
           </div>
        <button name="submit">upload</button>
    </form>
     <p></p>
    <ol>

     </ol>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in such way?

Comment: because this creates a link or url in the database in one form input if I can move the other contents to the other folders

Comment: allowing me to just place certain info in the link or url

Comment: You have two `id="fileToUpload"` in your code, which is invalid, `id` needs to be unique. The php manual itself has documentation on [uploading multiple files](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example you can adept it as per your need.

```
<form action="file_reciever.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

PHP code is like

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submission'] && $_POST['submission'] != null) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
            //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
                //Setup our new file path
                $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

                    //Your insert statement goes here

                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm still stuck with the tmp file as being the folder and turning this into an array which means that my results will output $_FILES['files']['name'][0], $_FILES['files']['name'][1], $_FILES['files']['name'][2],...etc

Comment: which than makes the insert into three variables that have to be placed into the database yet that doesn't match the html

Comment: What you have wrote in insert statement?

Comment: the problem I ran across is that when I use INSERT I no longer have the name or values from the html form. Now I have had a two file success on the INSERT yet not the move_to_file. when I have success on one there's no success on the other

Comment: Could you please add your code for better understanding?

Comment: let me ask a dumb question? Can we change the tmp_name? Like:

Comment: Like: $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] to $_FILES['name']['tmp_file']:?